# Items collection must be empty before using error

Tags: windows-phone-7, wpf-controls

I using the toolkit which provide the MultiSelectionList control in wp7, I am trying to bind the names to the multiselectItem using the property ItemsSource in C#.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="Please select the satellites from the list:-" />
      <toolkit:MultiselectList Name="multiSelectionList">
          <toolkit:MultiselectItem Content="{Binding Name}" />
      </toolkit:MultiselectList>
   </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

But I got this error.

```
Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.
```

I tested the service in other parts of the app and it is working with no issues.

Please advise me.Thanks,

Comment: where are you setting your 'MultiselectList' 'ItemsSource' and if you setting it in code then you should have an empty list but in the example above you are adding to the list a single Item. I think you tried to add a datatemplate to the MultiselectList and not an Item, or am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're adding an item to the `MultiSelectList` when you do:

```
<toolkit:MultiselectItem Content="{Binding Name}" />
```

By the time you assign the `ItemsSource`, which I assume you're doing in the code-behind somewhere, there is already an item in the list (the one above). This is why the error is getting thrown. You could manually clear the list before setting the source, but that's not necessarily considered good practice. What you could do instead is create a `DataTemplate`, not an actual instance of a `MultiSelectItem`. I'm not familiar with this control, but try:

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList Name="multiSelectionList">
  <toolkit:MultiSelectList.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <toolkit:MultiselectItem Content="{Binding Name}" />
     </DataTemplate>
  </toolkit:MultiSelectList.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:MultiselectList>
```

Comment: Great answer and very quick only forget one thing in the XAML. :) <toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    
                                </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>

Comment: I think I edited it just before you posted the comment :) (Unless I'm missing something...?)

Comment: Sorry maybe you didn't it could work like that too, just was a bit unusual for me i always used the syntax i added as comment here. :)

Comment: I noticed you a while back you answer very quick and very good and most of the time you are quicker then me. :) And we all make mistakes we are not machines or are we? :D

Comment: I've been doing WP7 dev for some time so a lot of the problems are things I've encountered and have been stuck on for days. Like to try and help so that people don't spend ages on them as well :)

Comment: I think the same way only i don't have so much experience as you do. And i do WP7 development now for fun, i'm sure it is fun to do it as a job too. :)